# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, rest

In a React app component which handles Facebook-like content feeds, I am running into an error:

> Feed.js:94 undefined "parsererror" "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

I ran into a similar error which turned out to be a typo in the HTML within the render function, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

More confusingly, I rolled the code back to an earlier, known-working version and I'm still getting the error.

Feed.js:

```
import React from 'react';

var ThreadForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {author: '', 
            text: '', 
            included: '',
            victim: ''
            }
  },
  handleAuthorChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value})
  },
  handleTextChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value})
  },
  handleIncludedChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({included: e.target.value})
  },
  handleVictimChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({victim: e.target.value})
  },
  handleSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var author = this.state.author.trim()
    var text = this.state.text.trim()
    var included = this.state.included.trim()
    var victim = this.state.victim.trim()
    if (!text || !author || !included || !victim) {
      return
    }
    this.props.onThreadSubmit({author: author, 
                                text: text, 
                                included: included,
                                victim: victim
                              })
    this.setState({author: '', 
                  text: '', 
                  included: '',
                  victim: ''
                  })
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
    <form className="threadForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Your name"
        value={this.state.author}
        onChange={this.handleAuthorChange} />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Say something..."
        value={this.state.text}
        onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name your victim"
        value={this.state.victim}
        onChange={this.handleVictimChange} />
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Who can see?"
        value={this.state.included}
        onChange={this.handleIncludedChange} />
      <input type="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
    )
  }
})

var ThreadsBox = React.createClass({
  loadThreadsFromServer: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        this.setState({data: data})
      }.bind(this),
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString())
      }.bind(this)
    })
  },
  handleThreadSubmit: function (thread) {
    var threads = this.state.data
    var newThreads = threads.concat([thread])
    this.setState({data: newThreads})
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: thread,
      success: function (data) {
        this.setState({data: data})
      }.bind(this),
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: threads})
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString())
      }.bind(this)
    })
  },
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {data: []}
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadThreadsFromServer()
    setInterval(this.loadThreadsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval)
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
    <div className="threadsBox">
      <h1>Feed</h1>
      <div>
        <ThreadForm onThreadSubmit={this.handleThreadSubmit} />
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
})

module.exports = ThreadsBox
```

In Chrome developer tools, the error seems to be coming from this function:

```
 loadThreadsFromServer: function loadThreadsFromServer() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        this.setState({ data: data });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

with the line `console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString()` underlined.

Since it looks like the error seems to have something to do with pulling JSON data from the server, I tried starting from a blank db, but the error persists. The error seems to be called in an infinite loop presumably as React continuously tries to connect to the server and eventually crashes the browser.

EDIT:

I've checked the server response with Chrome dev tools and Chrome REST client, and the data appears to be proper JSON.

EDIT 2:

It appears that though the intended API endpoint is indeed returning the correct JSON data and format, React is polling `http://localhost:3000/?_=1463499798727` instead of the expected `http://localhost:3001/api/threads`.

I am running a webpack hot-reload server on port 3000 with the express app running on port 3001 to return the backend data. What's frustrating here is that this was working correctly the last time I worked on it and can't find what I could have possibly changed to break it.

Comment: That suggests that your "JSON" is actually HTML. Look at the data you are getting back from the server.

Comment: This is the error you get if you do something like `JSON.parse("<foo>")` -- a JSON string (which you expect with `dataType: 'json'`) cannot begin with `<`.

Comment: As @quantin said, it can be html, maybe error of some sort, try the same url with some rest clients

Comment: like I mentioned, i tried it with an empty db (which returns simply []) and it still gives the same error

Comment: You most likely need to proxy API requests depending on your `NODE_ENV`. See this: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: @apsillers I think this is my problem. I am storing HTML strings with markup in my JSON object for display. Do I need to escape all the HTML characters for this to work?

Comment: my suggetion to use https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: I encountered this error as I used `if($_POST['key'])` instead of `if(isset($_POST['key']))` .Although this is a very silly and an amateur mistake, I hope some LIY dev like me might find this useful.

Comment: Check your package-lock.json, if there are merge conflicts, it will show this error.

Comment: Hi, in my case the same issue resolved when I simply changed the API uri from root "/" to something else, e.g. app.get("/data", (req, res)...) Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 240, accepted):

The wording of the error message corresponds to what you get from Google Chrome when you run `JSON.parse('<...')`. I know you said the server is setting `Content-Type:application/json`, but I am led to believe the response *body* is actually HTML.

> `Feed.js:94 undefined "parsererror" "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"`
>
> with the line `console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString())` underlined.

The `err` was actually thrown within `jQuery`, and passed to you as a variable `err`. The reason that line is underlined is simply because that is where you are logging it.

I would suggest that you add to your logging. Looking at the actual `xhr` (XMLHttpRequest) properties to learn more about the response. Try adding `console.warn(xhr.responseText)` and you will most likely see the HTML that is being received.

Comment: Thanks, I did this and you're right -- react is polling the wrong url and is returning the contents of index.html. I just can't find out why.

Comment: Thanks for the additional debugging statement, although I needed to use `console.warn(jqxhr.responseText)`.  That was very helpful in diagnosing my problem.

Comment: @Mimi314159, `console.log`, `console.warn` and `console.error` will all write to your Console. However, the Console will usually provide Logging Filter options, so be sure that those are enabled or disabled as you prefer.

Comment: In my case, a PHP error was occuring which caused the server to return HTML rather than valid JSON.

Comment: You can also got to Developer Settings -> Network Tab to see the response which you are actually getting. This happens when you are running backend and frontend on the same sever (e.g., localhost). To fix that, in the `package.json` inside your `React` root project folder, add this line: `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000" `, (or your port instead of `5000` you want your request back).

Answer (score 90):

You're receiving HTML (or XML) back from the server, but the `dataType: json` is telling jQuery to parse as JSON. Check the "Network" tab in Chrome dev tools to see contents of the server's response.

Comment: I checked, and it appears to be returning properly formatted json. Here's the response header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2487
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 17 May 2016 15:34:00 GMT
ETag:W/"9b7-yi1/G0RRpr0DlOVc9u7cMw"
X-Powered-By:Express

Comment: @AVI I believe you have to specify the MIME type in your resource class. (e.g) `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Answer (score 23):

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

### You are getting an HTML file (or XML) instead of json.

Html files begin with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I "achieved" this error by forgetting the `https://` in my `fetch` method:

```js
fetch(`/api.github.com/users/${login}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(setData);
```

### I verified my hunch:

I logged the response as text instead of JSON.

```js
fetch(`/api.github.com/users/${login}`)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => console.log(text))
    .then(setData);
```

Yep, an html file.

### Solution:

I fixed the error by adding back the `https://` in my `fetch` method.

```js
fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${login}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(setData)
    .catch(error => (console.log(error)));
```

Comment: Note to self: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text

Comment: In my case, this happens when accessing an API that is served through Cloudflare. Because the actual server is busy or unavailable for whatever reason, Cloudflare returns HTML instead with "522: Connection timed out" as its content.

Answer (score 19):

This ended up being a permissions problem for me. I was trying to access a URL I didn't have authorization for with CanCan, so the URL was switched to `users/sign_in`. The redirected URL responds to HTML, not json. The first character in an HTML response is `<`.

Comment: I had the same, although in ASP.NET MVC.  For other .NETters, I had forgotten to decorate my action with the [AllowAnonymous] attribute so the framework was trying to return me the unauthorized error in HTML which was crashing my AJAX call.

Comment: so what is the answer in that case

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I was getting this running webpack. It turned out to be corrupted somewhere in the local node_modules dir.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

...was enough to get it working right again.

Comment: along with this, I tried removing package-lock.json. Then it worked for me.

Comment: Removing node modules and a fresh npm install worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

I experienced this error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position", where the token 'm' can be any other characters.

It turned out that I missed one of the double quotes in the JSON object when I was using RESTconsole for DB test, as {"name: "math"}. The correct one should be {"name": "math"}.

It took me a lot effort to figure out this clumsy mistake. I am afraid others will run into similar issues.

Answer (score 10):

In a nutshell, if you're getting this error or a similar error, that means only one thing: Someplace in our codebase, we were expecting a valid JSON format to process, and we didn't get one. For example,

```
var string = "some string";
JSON.parse(string)
```

will throw an error, saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0

Because, the first character in `string` is `s` & it's not a valid JSON now. This can throw error in between also. like:

```
var invalidJSON= '{"foo" : "bar", "missedquotehere : "value" }';
JSON.parse(invalidJSON)
```

Will throw error:

```
VM598:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 36
```

because we intentionally missed a quote in the JSON string `invalidJSON` at position 36.

And if you fix that:

```
var validJSON= '{"foo" : "bar", "missedquotehere" : "value" }';
JSON.parse(validJSON)
```

will give you an object in JSON.

This error can be thrown in any place & in any framework/library. Most of the time you may be reading a network response which is not valid JSON. So steps of debugging this issue can be like:

1. `curl` or hit the actual API you're calling.
2. Log/Copy the response and try to parse it with `JSON.parse`. If you're getting error, fix it.
3. If not, make sure your code is not mutating/changing the original response.

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when you define the response as `application/json` and you are getting HTML as a response. Basically, this happens when you are writing server side script for specific URL with a response of JSON, but the error format is in HTML.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same issue.

I removed the `dataType:'json'` from the `$.ajax` method.

Answer (score 7):

Those who are using `create-react-app` and trying to fetch local json files.

As in `create-react-app`, `webpack-dev-server` is used to handle the request and for every request it serves the `index.html`. So you are getting

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.

To solve this, you need to eject the app and modify the `webpack-dev-server` configuration file.

You can follow the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368716/fetching-json-returns-error-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token/55628120#55628120).

Answer (score 6):

**For future googlers:**

***This message will be generated if the server-side function crashes.***

*Or if the server-side function doesn't even exist ( i.e. Typo in function name )*.

So - suppose you are using a GET request... and everything looks perfect and you've triple-checked everything...

Check that GET string one more time.  Mine was:

```
'/theRouteIWant&someVar=Some value to send'
```

should be

```
'/theRouteIWant?someVar=Some value to send'
               ^
```

***CrAsH !***        *( ...* ***invisibly***, *on the* ***server*** *...)*

Node/Express sends back the incredibly (non)helpful message:
`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`.

Per [Eliezer Berlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5243309/eliezer-berlin?tab=answers&sort=votes)'s comment, the `<` token is usually a piece of unexpected HTML, such as in `<head>`, being returned by the server.

Comment: The reason it's happening is because you're getting an HTML response instead of a JSON response. Your response probably begins with `<head>` or `<body>`, with the first letter being "**<**".

Answer (score 4):

In my case, for an Azure hosted Angular 2/4 site, my API call to `mySite/api/...` was redirecting due to mySite routing issues.  So, it was returning the HTML from the redirected page instead of the API JSON.  I added an exclusion in a web.config file for the API path.

I was not getting this error when developing locally, because the site and API were on different ports.  There is probably a better way to do this, but it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <clear />
 
        <!-- ignore static files -->
        <rule name="AngularJS Conditions" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(app/.*|css/.*|fonts/.*|assets/.*|images/.*|js/.*|api/.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="None" />
        </rule>
 
        <!--remaining all other url's point to index.html file -->
        <rule name="AngularJS Wildcard" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
        </rule>
 
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

2022 UPDATE: having written this several years ago.  I'd call this suggestion more of a workaround - a direct fix.  The better hosting pattern is to simply not try to host these `api` paths under your website path; rather, host them on separate base URLs entirely.  For my use case example, the API and Web path would be entirely separate Azure Web Services and would get different URL endpoints.

Comment: I had a similar issue with my Vue site.  Locally it worked fine, but once published, I would get 404 errors when refreshing URLs.  It had to do with rewriting the path for the API.  I followed the Vue Router instructions [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#internet-information-services-iis) ...but it still wasn't working.  I had to exclude the js/css/img directories from the redirect also.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error message following a tutorial. Our issue seems to be 'url: this.props.url' in the ajax call. In React.DOM when you are creating your element, mine looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox data="/api/comments" pollInterval={2000}/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Well, this `CommentBox` does not have a url in its props, just data. When I switched `url: this.props.url` -> `url: this.props.data`, it made the right call to the server and I got back the expected data.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I my case the error was a result of me not assigning my return value to a variable. The following caused the error message:

```
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("hello");
```

I changed it to:

```
string H = "hello";
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(H);
```

Without the variable JSON is unable to properly format the data.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I was getting the data back in a `string` which was not in a proper JSON format, which I was then trying to parse it. `simple example: JSON.parse('{hello there}')` will give an error at h. In my case the callback url  was returning an unnecessary character before the objects: `employee_names([{"name":....` and was getting error at e at 0. My callback URL itself had an issue which when fixed, returned only objects.

Answer (score 3):

On a general level this error occurs when a JSON object is parsed that has syntax errors in it. Think of something like this, where the message property contains unescaped double quotes:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "code": "1",
        "message": "This message has "unescaped" quotes, which is a JSON syntax error."
    }]
}
```

If you have JSON in your app somewhere then it's good to run it through [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to verify that it doesn't have a syntax error. Usually this isn't the case though in my experience, it's usually JSON returned from an API that's the culprit.

When an XHR request is made to an HTTP API that returns a response with a `Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8` header which contains invalid JSON in the response body you'll see this error.

If a server-side API controller is improperly handling a syntax error, and it's being printed out as part of the response, that will break the structure of JSON returned. A good example of this would be an API response containing a PHP Warning or Notice in the response body:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: something in <b>/path/to/some-api-controller.php</b> on line <b>99</b><br />
{
    "success": false,
    "data": [{ ... }]
}
```

95% of the time this is the source of the issue for me, and though it's somewhat addressed here in the other responses I didn't feel it was clearly described. Hopefully this helps, if you're looking for a handy way to track down which API response contains a JSON syntax error I've written an [Angular module for that](https://www.kevinleary.net/syntax-error-unexpected-token-json-position-0/).

Here's the module:

```
/**
 * Track Incomplete XHR Requests
 * 
 * Extend httpInterceptor to track XHR completions and keep a queue 
 * of our HTTP requests in order to find if any are incomplete or 
 * never finish, usually this is the source  of the issue if it's 
 * XHR related
 */
angular.module( "xhrErrorTracking", [
        'ng',
        'ngResource'
    ] )
    .factory( 'xhrErrorTracking', [ '$q', function( $q ) {
        var currentResponse = false;

        return {
            response: function( response ) {
                currentResponse = response;
                return response || $q.when( response );
            },
            responseError: function( rejection ) {
                var requestDesc = currentResponse.config.method + ' ' + currentResponse.config.url;
                if ( currentResponse.config.params ) requestDesc += ' ' + JSON.stringify( currentResponse.config.params );

                console.warn( 'JSON Errors Found in XHR Response: ' + requestDesc, currentResponse );

                return $q.reject( rejection );
            }
        };
    } ] )
    .config( [ '$httpProvider', function( $httpProvider ) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push( 'xhrErrorTracking' );
    } ] );
```

More details can be found in the blog article referenced above, I haven't posted everything found there here as it's probably not all relevant.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error while calling an API in React using the fetch API with the POST method.

Before:

```
fetch('/api/v1/tour',{
      method:"POST",
      headers:{"Content-type":"json/application"},
      body:JSON.stringify(info)
    })
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((json)=>{
      if(json.status === 'success')
        alert(json.message)
      else
        console.log('something went wrong :(')
    }).catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

I resolved the error by changing the headers to `{"Content-type":"application/json"}`:

After:

```
fetch('/api/v1/tour',{
      method:"POST",
      headers:{"Content-type":"application/json"},
      body:JSON.stringify(info)
    })
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((json)=>{
      if(json.status === 'success')
        alert(json.message)
      else
        console.log('something went wrong :(')
    }).catch(e=>console.log(e))
```

Answer (score 2):

Protip: Testing json on a local Node.js server? Make sure you don't already have something routing to that path

```
'/:url(app|assets|stuff|etc)';
```

Answer (score 2):

In python you can use json.Dump(str) before send result to html template.
with this command string convert to correct json format and send to html template. After send this result to JSON.parse(result) , this is correct response and you can use this.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that response is in JSON format otherwise fires this error.

Answer (score 2):

The possibilities for this error are overwhelming.

In my case, I found that the issue was adding the `homepage` filed in `package.json` caused the issue.

Worth checking: in `package.json` change:

```
homepage: "www.example.com"
```

to

```
hompage: ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Malformed JSON or HTML instead of JSON is the underlying cause of this issue, as described by the other answers, however in my case I couldn't reliably replicate this error, as if the server was sometimes returning valid JSON, and other times returning something else like an HTML error page or similar.

In order to avoid it breaking the page altogether, I resorted to manually trying to parse the returned content, and share it in case it helps anyone else resolve it for them.

```js
const url = "https://my.server.com/getData";

fetch(url).then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) return; // call failed

  response.text().then(shouldBeJson => { // get the text-only of the response
    let json = null;
    try {
      json = JSON.parse(shouldBeJson); // try to parse that text
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e); // json parsing failed
      return;
    };
    if (!json) return; // extra check just to make sure we have something now.

    // do something with my json object
  });
});
```

While this obviously doesn't resolve the root cause of the issue, it can still help to handle the issue a bit more gracefully and take some kind of reasonable action in instances when it fails.

Answer (score 2):

For the React app made by CRA there are two main problems we might face while fetching the JSON data of any `<dummy.json>`
file.

I have my dummy.json file in my project and am trying to fetch the JSON data from that file but I got two errors:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 .
```

I got an HTML file rather than actual JSON Data in the response in the Network tab in Chrome or any browser.

Here are the main two reasons behind that which solved my issue.

1. Your JSON data is invalid in your JSON file.
2. It might be that the JSON file did not load properly for this so you just restart your React server. This is my issue, *within* React.

React direct running or access the public folder not the src folder.

How I solved it:

I moved my file into the public folder and access is directly in any file of the src folder.

[image: My public folder]

Making a REST call in the Redux action.js:

```
export const fetchDummy = ()=>{
return (dispatch)=>{
        dispatch(fetchDummyRequest());
        fetch('./assets/DummyData.json')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(result => {
            dispatch(fetchDummySuccess(result))
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          dispatch(fetchDummyFailure(err))
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, I get this error, when API throws an error with text format.
What I suggest is to see the error text content to figure out what is wrong going on.

1. jQuery =>
   set dataType: 'text'
2. fetch =>
   reponse.text() instead of reponse.json()

Answer (score 2):

This error usually occurs when HTML is returned by the endpoint.

So, check the endpoint address that you are making the request.
If it's misspelled or if there are some unhandled invalid values in the request, these may be the reason for the endpoint returning HTML response.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time with this, I found out that in my case the problem was having "homepage" defined on my package.json file made my app not work on firebase (same 'token' error).
I created my react app using create-react-app, then I used the firebase guide on the READ.me file to deploy to github pages, realized I had to do extra work for the router to work, and switched to firebase. github guide had added the homepage key on package.json and caused the deploy issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this happened when one of the properties on the object I was returning as JSON threw an exception.

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Clients { get; set; }
public int CRCount
{
    get
    {
        var count = 0;
        //throws when Clients is null
        foreach (var c in Clients) {
            count += c.Value;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Adding a null check, fixed it for me:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> Clients { get; set; }
public int CRCount
{
    get
    {
        var count = 0;
        if (Clients != null) {
            foreach (var c in Clients) {
                count += c.Value;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just something basic to check, make sure you dont have anything commented out in the json file

```
//comments here will not be parsed and throw error
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be old. But it just occurred in Angular where the content type for request and response were different in my code. So check headers for

```
 let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        **Accept**: 'application/json'
    });
```

in React axios

```
axios({
  method:'get',
  url:'http://  ',
 headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },
  responseType:'json'
})
```

jQuery Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
**headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },**
      cache: false,
      success: function (data) {
        this.setState({ data: data });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

For some, this may help you guys:
I had a similar experience with Wordpress REST API. I even used Postman to check if I had the correct routes or endpoint. I later found out that I accidentally put an "echo" inside my script - hooks:

[Debug & check your console](https://www.screencast.com/t/AvM4tHy7lT3H)

[Cause of the error](https://www.screencast.com/t/phTJbOqFo)

So basically, this means that I printed a value that isn't JSON that is mixed with the script that causes AJAX error - "SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 0"

Answer (score 1):

In my case (backend), I was using res.send(token);

Everything got fixed when I changed to res.send(data);

You may want to check this if everything is working and posting as intended, but the error keeps popping up in your front-end.

Answer (score 1):

In my Case there was problem with "Bearer" in header ideally it should be "Bearer "(space after the end character) but in my case it was "Bearer" there was no space after the character. Hope it helps some one!

Answer (score 1):

If you receive this error in a Chrome extension it can be tough to track down, especially if it occurs when you install the extension. However, I found a way that makes it easier.

I had a Chrome extension that called some scripts from my web server on installation of the plugin, pulling down some default settings. I received the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in _generated_background_page.html
```

When you get this go into Extensions, find your extension, click the "background page" hyperlink, and the inspector will open for it. Then, go to Network and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Now, you'll see all the things that the background page had to load.

Click on each one, especially ones that connect back to a remote server. You'll see Headers in the Network tab, followed by a Preview. Look at the Preview for each of the items. If you see something other than the expected header for this data, or you see errors, then that's likely your cause.

In my case, my server script was calling another script and that script had a bug in it because of missing variables at runtime, which then made my `application/json` header not match with the data it was sending, resulting in the unexpected token error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when sending the data in the test API node the JSON object had an extra comma at the end like:

```js
POST   http://localhost:9000/api/posts/ 
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "title": "sokka",
    "description": "hope this works",
    "username": "sokka blog4",
}
```

so I only needed to remove the extra comma and send this kind of data:

```js
POST   http://localhost:9000/api/posts/ 
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "title": "sokka",
    "description": "hope this works",
    "username": "sokka blog4"
}
```

I was using the RESTclient extension to test my API.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers, it also happens when your API response includes

```
<?php{username: 'Some'}
```

which could be a case when your backend is using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This might cause due to your javascript code is looking at some json response and you received something else like text.

Comment: Please elaborate while giving answers rather than giving one liners, unless they outright solve answers. The explanation would help the answer-seekers understand the solution better.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run this line of code in the console:

```
JSON.parse(undefined);
```

you will get the same error message:

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
```

Therefore, your app is trying to parse an invalid JSON `undefined`.

Comment: Think carefully about that logic. Parsing `undefined` is only ONE way to get that error. Trying (for example) `JSON.parse('<')` is another.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone else is using fetch from the "Using Fetch" documentation on Web API's in Mozilla:
(This is really useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
  fetch(api_url + '/database', {
    method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: qrdata //notice that it is not qr but qrdata
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })  
  .catch((error) => {
  console.error('Error:', error);  });
```

This was inside the function:

```
async function postQRData(qr) {

  let qrdata = qr; //this was added to fix it!
  //then fetch was here
}
```

I was passing into my function `qr` what I believed to be an object because `qr` looked like this: `{"name": "Jade", "lname": "Bet", "pet":"cat"}` but I kept getting syntax errors. 
When I assigned it to something else: `let qrdata = qr;` it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe some permission error would be there just try switching the browser and log in from an authorized account.

Comment: Please use the answer option if you are sure about the solution, else you can choose to write it as a comment to the question.

Comment: In my case this works therefore writing it as answer.

Answer (score -10):

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

A simple solution to this error is to write a comment in `styles.less` file.

Comment: This is one of the most bizarre answers I've ever seen on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi there!  When posting a comment, make sure it's entirely applicable to the actual question being asked.  Your answer could be better if you tell us why exactly writing comments in a `styles.less` file could possibly solve what appears to be a back-end server code issue.