# Routing to pass parameters Laravel 5.3 and AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.3

I have to pass parameters per post with ajax but not working on the console I get this:

> POST http://localhost:8000/prueba2 405 (Method Not Allowed)

This is my routing:

```
Route::get('prueba2', 'HomeController@index');
```

This is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{url('prueba2')}}',
    type: 'POST', // Send post data
    data: 'type=fetch',
    async: false,
    success: function(s){
        json_events = s;
    }
});
```

This is my controller:

```
public function index(){

    return 'hola';
}
```

All this is a test and is not the final driver nor the final ajax, but it seems to be some response by the controller. But unfortunately I get a 405.
If someone can help me with this serious problem it would be a lot of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving a MethodNotAllowedException because you defined a *GET route* with `Route::get('prueba2', 'HomeController@index');`, but you do a *POST request*.

Change your AJAX type to GET or use `Route::post()`.

The last one would look like:

```
Route::post('prueba2', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: One question, do you know what this error means?: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token H in JSON at position 0 @manniL

Comment: I'm certainly not sure, but you can may refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-in-react-app