# How to fix: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json, mongodb, angular, typescript, mongoose

> I kept getting the error in the title of this post. So I removed my .json() from response.json()
>   my below code `return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sign-up', body, {headers: headers})
>               .map((response: Response) => response.json())`
>   However, now I am getting as an error:

```
Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵    <base …src="/js/app/bundle.js"></script>↵</body>↵</html>",
```

I am new to web development, and I'm trying to use code from an online course I took. I know my console.log should be an object and not this 'Response'. How do I get my returned data to be the information I submitted through an html form?

Also, I am leaving the .json() in my code posted below that way it shows what I originally had to get the `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` error. But like I said, I removed that .json() and got the `Response {_body: "<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵    <base …src="/js/app/bundle.js"></script>↵</body>↵</html>",` error

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { User } from "./user.model";
import { ErrorService } from "../errors/error.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private errorService: ErrorService) {}

    signup(user: User) {
        const body = JSON.stringify(user);
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sign-up', body, {headers: headers})
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
            // .catch((error: Response) => {
            //     this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
            //     return Observable.throw(error.json());
            // });
    }
}
```

> Next Class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { User } from "./user.model";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-signup',
    templateUrl: './signup.component.html'
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
    myForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    onSubmit() {
        const user = new User(
            this.myForm.value.email,
            this.myForm.value.password,
            this.myForm.value.firstName,
            this.myForm.value.lastName,
            this.myForm.value.age,
            this.myForm.value.goal
        );
        this.authService.signup(user)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                error => console.error(error)
            );
        this.myForm.reset();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            lastName: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            email: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?")
            ]),
            password: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            age: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
            goal: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the server returns null, which can't be parsed to json.

Comment: I think you are getting plain text with html content and trying to treat it as a json string.

Comment: Would you guys mind elaborating a little bit more? Like I said, I'm brand new to web development so I wouldn't know how to change anything like this. Thanks!

Comment: Try this. Just ignore my comments about OOPS. Hope this helps:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121284/angular-2-mean-stack-receiving-json-instead-of-html

Comment: @harold_mean2 you sir are my hero! The link you posed didn't have my specific fix but it was VERY close to what my problem was. i would've never thought to have checked there if it weren't for your link

Comment: My answer to your question would be much more complicated. I am using passport, jwt, Bcrypt for authentication. The link though should get you started. Good luck. You do not mind up voting my answer? Have a nice day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095762/error-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the content you are getting back, you are receiving an `HTML` content while your code is expecting a `json` content. All you have to do is configure your server to return `json` instead, or fix your code to handle `HTML` response.

Comment: So why wouldn't the `response.json()` accomplish this?

Comment: The `.json()` function is responsible of turning a string formatted in a `JSON` notation to a `JSON` object, what you have isn't formatted as `JSON` it is formatted as `HTML`! So the `.json()` function could not turn it into a `JSON` object

Comment: But shouldn't the `const body = JSON.stringify(user);` be the string formatted in `JSON` your referring to? Then I called the `.json()` after.

Comment: But your are not calling the `.json()` on the body variable, you are applying it on the response you get back from your server after you post to `"http://localhost:3000/sign-up"`, which is an `HTML` response.

Comment: So what could be my way of fixing this?

Comment: Configure your server to return a `JSON` object that contains the info you need about that user.

Comment: Thank you for your help! One of the users above posted a link that was able to fix my issue.

Comment: I am glad to hear that :)