# async fetch - SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, ajax, fetch

I'm trying to make a ReactJS app that utilizes the [*Spotify* API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit_grant_flow), but I keep receiving this error:

[image]

```
const client_id = ''; //hidden
const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3000/'
let accessToken;

const Spotify = {
    async getAccessToken(){
        if (accessToken){
            return accessToken;
        }

        try{
            let response = await fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=${client_id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}`);
            if (response.ok){
                let jsonResponse = await response.json();
                console.log(jsonResponse);
            }
        }catch (e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}

export default Spotify;
```

I've read around and I hear this is a *server-side* issue? If so, is there a work-around it? By the way I am using this `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` to prevent the CORS error.

Thanks for any help. I'll keep working on it. If I find anything, I'll post up the solution right away!

Comment: Provide the complete and exact response body.

Comment: The response you get to your `fetch` request is **not** a valid json, so you can't `response.json()` it. This question is not related at all to javascript nor reactjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-in-react-app

Comment: With that error, chances are good that the response data you are getting is actually HTML

Comment: ok guys i'll take your suggestions!