# Fetching JSON returns error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 and status code 304: Not Modified

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to fetch a JSON file but it returns the errors **Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0** and **304: Not Modified**. I tried to add headers `'Content-Type': 'application/json` and `'Accept': 'application/json'` but then it returns error **404: Not found**.

Here is the code where I am fetching my JSON:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class LabExperiment extends React.Component {

componentWillMount() {
    const readmePath = require("./docs/iat/iatDependency.json");

    fetch("./docs/iat/iatDependency.json")
    .then(response => {
        response.json();
    })
    .then(text => {
        console.log(text);
    });
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>Hello</div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my json file:

```
{
    "js": [
        "../jsPsych/jspsych.js",
        "../jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-iat-image.js",
        "../jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-iat-html.js",
        "../jsPsych/plugins/jspsych-html-keyboard-response.js"
    ],
    "css": [
        "../jsPsych/css/jspsych.css"
    ]
}
```

I also at one point tried to use `response.text()` instead of `json()` but it returned my index.html file.

I have been looking around the web for the past week trying to find a solution but what worked for others didn't work for me. Any advice?

EDIT: 
When I did `console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type'))` it returned `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. Shouldn't it already be application/json? Why is the initial encoding 'text/html'?

Comment: It looks like somehow you are getting an html file instead of json

Comment: Yes, I know that. I have been trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: If you're using Express, try `res.json(myJson)`. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json

Comment: That also just returns an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`.

Comment: 304 means page is unchanged since you last checked. (So if you clear the cache it shouldn't 304 on the next attempt, but will again after that.) I don't know why `fetch` mis-handles this. I suspect the body explains the 304, like they sometimes do with 404 etc. Try `fetch("./docs/iat/iatDependency.json", {cache: ... })`, using values listed for `cache` at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch . Also, a 304 response shouldn't have a body according to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-4.1 ; perhaps that has confused it.

Comment: I'm getting `application/json` as my content type, and it works when developing on localhost, and I've confirmed the file is accessible online by viewing source, but I still get `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Answer (score 1):

Check Whether You have the .env file with
`REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3001`
in it. The file should be in the root folder.

Answer (score -2):

I think you might be using `create-react-app`. As in `create-react-app`,  `webpack-dev-server` is used to handle the request and for every request it serves the `index.html`. So you are getting

> Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 and status code 304: Not Modified

So to solve this, you can do following:

1. Run `npm run eject`

After that `config` folder is created at the root of the app.

2. Go to `config/webpackDevServer.config.js`.
3. Then we need to set `disableDotRule: false` in `webpackDevServer.config.js`.

   ```
       historyApiFallback: {
        // previously disableDotRule: true,
        disableDotRule: false,
       },
   ```
4. Keep your json file i.e `docs/iat/iatDependency.json` in `public` folder.
5. Use `fetch('/docs/iat/iatDependency.json').then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log('data', data))`