# How to fectch API in React JS?

Tags: json, reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch Data form OpenWeather API.According to the docs the response is JSON.However I am getting an error of :

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${CITY_NAME}&appid=${API_KEY}`)
.then(
  (res)=> res.json()
  .then((data)=>{
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error)
  })
)
}, [])
```

I also have a status code of 304: Not Modified when I looked through the developers tool.

There were few question which matched my problem but none of them solve my problem like:
[Fetching JSON returns error Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368716/fetching-json-returns-error-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token/55628120)  and

[React Js: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269808/react-js-uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-posit)

Comment: @yudhiesh Yes!! It is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to the API is incorrect and should be
`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${CITY_NAME}&appid=${API_KEY}` instead.