# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 - React app in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, proxy, rails-api, procfile

I'm working on a Rails 5.0.6 as an API. I am also running a React application for the front end running on a node server version v9.8.0. On the React app which is running on `localhost:3000` I get the following error:[image]

The rails is used as an API so in the controllers I return `@drinks` in json format.

drinks_controller.rb

```
class DrinksController < ApiController
  # GET /drinks
  def index
    @drinks = Drink.select("id,title").all

    render json: @drinks.to_json
  end

  # GET /drinks/1
  def show
    @drink = Drink.find(params[:id])
    render json: @drink.to_json(:include => { :ingredients => { :only => [:id, :description] }})
  end
end
```

I run both servers locally using `Procfile` in `Profile.dev`

```
web: cd client && PORT=3000 npm start
api: PORT=3001 && bundle exec rails s
```

When I go to the rails server which is running on `localhost:3001/api/drinks` I get the following:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Sparkling Negroni"},{"id":2,"title":"Pineapple-Jalapeño Margarita"}]
```

which is in json format, On the app.js im fetching from that endpoint

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.fetch('api/drinks')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

Is it the proxy not working?

```
{
  "name": "package-json",
  "version": "4.0.1",
  "description": "Get metadata of a package from the npm registry",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": "sindresorhus/package-json",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "author": {
    "name": "Sindre Sorhus",
    "email": "sindresorhus@gmail.com",
    "url": "sindresorhus.com"
  }
```

I can't understand what the issue is?

[image]

Comment: I see that you are using the developer toolbar, what is going on in your network panel?  What response is returned by your server?

Comment: @JoseJimenez I updated the post with an image of the network

Comment: Just to be sure, try `window.fetch('/api/drinks')`

Comment: @StevenAguilar you can click on your /api/drinks line in the network panel and look for a "response" or "preview" tab in the resulting screen.  It should show you what is coming back from your rails applicaiton.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" in React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-in-react-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your rails app is returning html when fetch is expecting JSON... The `<` character is indicative that an HTML string is being delivered, (the JSON parser is choking on HTML).

Try dumping the response "as is" to see what you're receiving.

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.fetch('api/drinks')
      .then(response => {
         console.log(response.status);
         console.log(response.body);
         return response.json();
      })
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```