# Angular 5 Http api request gets response in chrome dev tools but won't return

Tags: angular, http, http-headers

I have a "Response" content :

[image]

But I can't console.log it.

Update (15:00 22/03/2018, this is new version) :

in actions.component.ts :

```
 generatePOR(){
    this._api.exportToERP(this.selection).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('heelo I am second phase');
      console.log(res);
    }, (error) => console.log(error), () => {});
  }
```

in api.ts :

```
generatePOR (idList): any {
  const apiURL = `${this.API_URL}/purchaseorders/generatePOR`;
  return this._http.post(apiURL, idList, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
}
```

here is is the console log :

```
ro {headers: Ge, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/purchaseorders/generatePOR", ok: false, …}error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttp…, text: "PARTNER_RELATION_CUSTOMER_GROUPCODE;PARTNER_RELATI…95;2;NEW ORDER PUBLISHED;;;2017-10-289 08:00:00
↵"}headers: Ge {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/purchaseorders/generatePOR"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 200statusText: "OK"url: "http://localhost:8080/purchaseorders/generatePOR"__proto__: eo
```

Update (16:31) :

```
generatePOR (idList): any {
    const apiURL = `${this.API_URL}/purchaseorders/generatePOR`;
    this.PORresult = this._http.post(apiURL, idList, {
      observe: 'response',
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
      responseType: 'text' as 'text'
    })
      .map((res, i) => {
        console.log('hi');
        console.log(res);
      });
    return this.PORresult;
  }
```

output :

```
hi  
ao {headers: Ge, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/purchaseorders/generatePOR", ok: true, …}body: "PARTNER_RELATION_CUSTOMER_GROUPCODE;PARTNER_RELATION_CUSTOMER_PLANTCODE;PO_UpdateVersion;PARTNER_RELATION_SUPPLIER_NOLOCAL;PO_PoNumber;PO_PosNumber;PO_RequestNumber;PARTNER_RELATION_SUPPLIER_NO;PO_CollabPrice;PO_CollabPromQty;PO_Status;PO_SupAckNumber;PO_CollabComment;PO_CollabPromDate
↵PARTNER_RELATION_CUSTOMER_GROUPCODE;PARTNER_RELATION_CUSTOMER_PLANTCODE;1;PARTNER_RELATION_SUPPLIER_NOLOCAL;4500634818;00070;0001;PARTNER_RELATION_SUPPLIER_NO;464.95;2;NEW ORDER PUBLISHED;;;2017-10-289 08:00:00
↵"headers: Ge {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}ok: truestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: 4url: "http://localhost:8080/purchaseorders/generatePOR"__proto__: eo

heelo I am second phase  undefined
```

Comment: You want to log the error or the success ?

Comment: i'd much rather have the success, if i shut down the server the error log runs fine. I want the response contents.

Comment: Sure, could you log the response before your if and post its content in an [edit] of your post ? Not as an image, but as text, please

Comment: You should subscribe to observables
`this._http.post(apiURL, idList, { observe: 'response' }, ).subscribe((res) => console.log(res));`

Comment: @mxr7350 the error I get lead me to this  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0-in-react-app

apparently I'm console.logging something that first needs to be parsed. End result I actually want to download the result as an Excel .csv file so maybe the logging step just to see that I have the result is extra work. but I can't use what they suggest both `xhr` and `jqxhr` are unrecognized by my IDE.

Comment: is the issue that getting response from POST is simply impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day and a half of toiling here's what worked for me :

actions.component.ts :

```
generatePOR(){
  this._api.generatePOR(this.selection).subscribe(res => {
    if(res !== null && res !== undefined){
      console.log(res.body);
    }
  }, (error) => console.log(error), () => {});
}
```

api.ts :

```
generatePOR(idList): any {
  const apiURL = `${this.API_URL}/purchaseorders/generatePOR`;
  this.PORresult = this._http.post(apiURL, idList, {
    observe: 'response',
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
    responseType: 'text' as 'text'
  }).catch(this.handleError);
  return this.PORresult;
}
```

...and making sure the backends send an actual file in the `text/csv` format and not just brute `html`.

this github thread helped alot in the creation of correct header and options : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586

note: you **must** make both inline to the api call you cannot declare them as variables beforehand in the function or elsewhere in the class or application.
also the nonsensical parsing : `responseType: 'text' as 'text'` is a big key factor in making it work.

Answer (score 1):

use .body to get the body of your response

```
if (res) {
      if (res.status === 201) {
        return [{ status: res.status, json: res.body }]
      }
      else if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log('hello, I am a result ',res);
        return [{ status: res.status, json: res.body }]
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are returning promise is wrong here.

```
generatePOR (idList): Observable<any> {
const apiURL = `${this.API_URL}/purchaseorders/generatePOR`;
return this._http.post(apiURL, idList, { observe: 'response' }, )
  .map((res: HttpResponse<any>, i) => {
    if (res) {
      if (res.status === 201) {
        return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
      }
      else if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log('hello, I am a result ',res);
        return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
      }
    }
  })
  .catch((error: any) => {
    if (error.status < 400 ||  error.status ===500) {
      return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
    }
  })
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

}

don't return this.results, return the the promise directly . Because api may take time. But before that you are returning the results object. That is the reason you are not getting that data.

Comment: He is not using promises he is using observables

Comment: I'm willing to use either so long as it works but I prefer observables.