# Problem when inserting sql query to my database php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert a row to my database table and I do not understand why the table is not inserted, I collect the data well from the form, the connection is fine and the query I think is well formed.

The data is correctly set that I have printed, the connection does not give an error and the console does not show any failure.

I do not understand what problem there is.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$dbname     = "recepop";

// Create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

$ingredientes    = $_POST['ingrediente'];
$titulo          = $_POST['buscador'];
$idusuario       = NULL;
$elaboracion     = $_POST['paso'];
$categorias      = $_POST['categorias'];
$imagenPrincipal = $_POST['imaPrin'];
$imagenes        = $_POST['ima'];
$personas        = (int) $_POST['pers'];
echo $personas;
echo $titulo;
echo $ingredientes;
echo $elaboracion;
echo $categorias;
echo $valoracion = NULL;
echo $imagenPrincipal;
echo $imagenes;
$fecha = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$contenido       = "".$ingredientes.$elaboracion;

//rename("imagenes/".$imagen, "imagenes/".$imagenFinal);
$query = "INSERT INTO recetas (titulo, contenido, fecha, idusuario, valoracion, imagenprincipal, imagenes, comensales) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

if ($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $titulo, $contenido, $fecha, $idusuario, $valoracion, $imagenPrincipal, $imagenes, $personas);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Inserted";
        //header('Location: mostrar.php?usu='.$_GET['usu']."&pass=".$_GET['pass']);
    } else {
        // Do some logging
        error_log($stmt->error);
        echo "Not inserted";
    }
} else {
    // Do some logging
    error_log($connection->error);
    echo "Not inserted";
}


$connection->close();
```

**Table SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recetas` (
  `idreceta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titulo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `contenido` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `idusuario` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `imagenprincipal` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `valoracion` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagenes` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci,
  `comensales` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idreceta`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

INSERT INTO `recetas` (`idreceta`, `titulo`, `contenido`, `fecha`, `idusuario`, `imagenprincipal`, `valoracion`, `imagenes`, `comensales`) VALUES
(1, 'Paella mixta', '<ul class=\"list-group\">\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Cras justo odio</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Morbi leo risus</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Vestibulum at eros</li>\r\n</ul>', '2019-01-15', '1', 'paella.jpg', NULL, NULL, 0),
(2, 'Boquerones', '<ul class=\"list-group\">\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Cras justo odio</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Morbi leo risus</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Vestibulum at eros</li>\r\n</ul>', '2019-01-24', '1', 'boquerones.jpg', NULL, NULL, 0),
(3, 'Salchichas', '<ul class=\"list-group\">\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Cras justo odio</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Morbi leo risus</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>\r\n  <li class=\"list-group-item\">Vestibulum at eros</li>\r\n</ul>', '2019-01-24', '1', 'salchi.jpg', NULL, NULL, 0);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: This looks like a JavaScript/client-side error.

Comment: Moreover it's from a browser extension, which makes the SQL part even less relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0)

Comment: I have solved the error of the client part, it is seen that I had activated the adblock and I am generating an error in the console, I have deactivated it and it is still not inserted so I do not understand what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two variables in the prepared statement that you didn't assign a value from the get request.

$contenido and $idusuario

and since you're using javascript to get the result back as JSON you're not seeing the actual error try accessing the file directly from your localhost so you can print the error and see what's going on.
but for now when i assigned a value for the variables i mentioned above the row was inserted sucessfully