# Post API is not working giving error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

this is the API call

```
export const socialPostUpdateBio = (publicKey,sig,about)=>{  

  let data=
  "pub="+ publicKey+
  "&sig="+ sig.sig+
  "&about="+about

  console.log('====',data)

  fetch('https://endpoint/postUpdateBio', {
method: 'POST',
headers: new Headers({
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
  Accept: "application/json"
}),
body:data
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  console.log("New post updateBio",responseJson);
  return responseJson.movies;
})
.catch((error) => {
console.error(error);
});
}
```

**this is data about:Its coming as a string not as a object**

```
{name:"Guruprakash Gupta",dob:"14/08/1997",location:"Bangalore",bio:"Gratitude",sex:"Male",profile_pic:"QmdDjpQ3G6vg7zkU2BBPMQJYsnnRtTEDEtL9xBXjvPh4i4-image-jpg"}
```

before api call we have a one more function where we are signing the data with private key,so signing of data is correct here so i haven't inculded that function.

this is what response im getting

```
Response {type: "default", status: 524, ok: false, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers, …}type: "default"status: 524ok: falsestatusText: undefinedheaders: Headers {map: {…}}url: "https://murmurjapi.wandx.co/accounts/postUpdateBio"_bodyInit: Blobdata: (...)size: (...)type: (...)_data: {size: 4831, offset: 0, blobId: "d07d8515-51de-48c1-950d-7d9a77c8c640"}size: 4831offset: 0blobId: "d07d8515-51de-48c1-950d-7d9a77c8c640"__proto__: Object__proto__: Objectdata: (...)size: (...)type: (...)constructor: ƒ Blob()slice: ƒ slice(start, end)close: ƒ close()get data: ƒ ()set data: ƒ (data)get size: ƒ ()get type: ƒ ()__proto__: Object_bodyBlob: Blob {_data: {…}}__proto__: ObjectbodyUsed: false_initBody: ƒ (body)blob: ƒ ()arrayBuffer: ƒ ()text: ƒ ()formData: ƒ ()json: ƒ ()clone: ƒ ()constructor: ƒ Response(bodyInit, options)__proto__: Object
```

Comment: your question is not clear, what problem are you facing?

Comment: when im calling the api, its throwing an error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0,in API im sending only 3 data public_key,sign, and about, so all my data is correct then why im getting this error ?

Comment: just put console.log(response) in the first then(), and please edit the question with the response. I think response itself not coming as json. we want to verify that

Comment: i have update it as u asked it ,please check it

Comment: please undo the changes and add the responseJson in the question? please show that also

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0)

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving HTML (or XML) back from the server, but response.json() telling XML or HTML to parse as JSON. Parser cannot parse XML or HTML, so it's showing this error. Check the "Network" tab in Chrome dev tools or postman client to see contents of the server's response.