# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (React/Redux App)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I am trying to signup/login a user using JWT. For this I have a working API which I have created.

Now, I want to use that authentication API with my React/Redux App.

When a user signs up I `dispatch` an action from my Signup component -

```
const signUpHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    dispatch(signup(name, email, password));
  };
```

Now, in my `userSlice` I have the following reducer -

```
signup: (state, action) => {
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/user/signup", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(action.payload),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    },
```

After I click on Signup i.e; after the `fetch` process begins, I get this error -

**Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

After digging in a little bit, I found that this error occurs when the return type from `fetch` is not JSON. But my API works prefectly fine.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check what the response is. Since it starts with `<` it's very likely HTML and it's very likely that you get an error page that will direct you to what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0)

Comment: In the Networks tab, the response is HTML which is a boilerplate with the same error above in a <p> tag

Comment: I know that the response is HTML but what can I do to rectify it?

Comment: You can update the `signup` POST response to be in JSON format instead of HTML. Also check the network event response code.

Comment: You mean in `headers` should I add `Accept: "application/json",` ? The response code is 400.

Comment: You don't need to stringify the body, and I think you meant `Content-type` instead of `Content-Type`?

Comment: Shouldn't we sent data to the server in JSON format using stringify ? `action.payload` is just a JS object

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the mistake and it was quite silly. This might prevent someone from committing the same mistake.

When dispatching the signup/login action,

instead of `dispatch(signup(name, email, password));`

Do -
`dispatch(signup({name, email, password}));`

The main error was the `action.payload` was not what was expected(i.e; an object). As a result of which the data sent to the server was incorrect.