# login to azure AD with nextauth

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to config login with azure AD using nextauth.
It is working in localhost but in build or in production it doesn’t work.

the error I'm getting is shown below.

[image]

this is the custom provider:

```
providers: [
{
  id: "msal",
  name: "Microsoft Login",
  type: "oauth",
  version: "2.0",
  scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read",
  params: { grant_type: "authorization_code" },
  accessTokenUrl: process.env.MSAL_TOKEN_ACCESS,
  requestTokenUrl: process.env.MSAL_TOKEN_REQUEST,
  authorizationUrl: process.env.MSAL_TOKEN_AUTHORIZE,
  profileUrl: "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo",
  profile: (profile) => {
    // console.log(profile);
    return {
      id: profile.sub,
      name: profile.name,
      last_name: profile.family_name,
      first_name: profile.given_name,
      email: profile.email,
    };
  },
  clientId: process.env.MS_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.MS_CLIENT_SECRET,
},
],
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0

Comment: Seems you are still using localhost endpoint on your production env?

Comment: @StanleyGong im using localhost in build. in production im using azure env inside app settings

Comment: Do you still need help on this?