# PHP search through JSON file and return an array that is equal to a value sent through a jQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, leaflet

TL;DR: I apologise for how unnecessary this task is.

**Outline**:
I have a portfolio project that I had completed, but apparently, I haven't done it according to the specification. So I have been instructed to redo a large portion of it in line with their guidelines.

It is a Gazetteer website project using `leaflet.js` and it must be constructed using jQuery, plain javaScript, and PHP routines to access multiple APIs to populate different Bootstrap Modals. I have produced something that I personally believe works perfectly well enough for the scope of this portfolio project.

You can try it out yourself here: https://kizzysinar.co.uk/project1/index.html

I was given this file: `countryBorders.geo.json`, which contains a bunch of different features:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Bahamas",
        "iso_a2": "BS",
        "iso_a3": "BHS",
        "iso_n3": "044"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [-77.53466,23.75975],
              [-77.78,23.71],
              [-78.03405,24.28615],
              [-78.40848, 24.57564],
              [-78.19087,25.2103],
              [-77.89,25.17],
              [-77.54,24.34],
              [-77.53466,23.75975]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [-77.82,26.58],
              [-78.91,26.42],
              [-78.98,26.79],
              [-78.51,26.87],
              [-77.85,26.84],
              [-77.82,26.58]
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              [-77,26.59],
              [-77.17255,25.87918],
              [-77.35641,26.00735],
              [-77.34,26.53],
              [-77.78802,26.92516],
              [-77.79,27.04],
              [-77,26.59]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }, 
    {..... MORE FEATURES
  ]
}
```

I was under the impression that I *could* use the file to populate the `<select>` dropdown options and to generate the map borders.
I utilised this **locally stored file** in the following ways:

1. Used it to populate the `<select>` dropdown box:

```
result['data'].features.forEach(function (feature) {
                $("<option>", {
                    value: feature.properties.iso_a3,
                    text: feature.properties.name
                }).appendTo("#countrySelect")
```

2. Since this is a **locally stored file** I chose to use the `leaflet.ajax` to parse the coordinates in the `countryBorders.geo.json` and create a layer of the multi polygons (features->properties->geometry->coordinates) for each `feature`.

```
var geoJSONLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('vendors/json/countryBorders.geo.json',{
    style: myStyle, 
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(mymap);
```

To zoom into/ set the view of the map when the user selected a country, I used the stored `value: feature.properties.iso_a3` to send an AJAX request to REST Countries API using the iso_a3 code to set the map view to the selected country according to the `latlng` of the returned results:

```
function setView() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/locateCountry.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            iso: $('#countrySelect option:selected').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                mymap.setView(result['coordinates']);

            }
      
        },
```

**Problem**:
But I, apparently, must use jQuery/AJAX to make a PHP request to access that **locally stored** `countryBorders.geo.json` and return the `coordinates` that match a given `iso_a3`. It's bonkers, and in my opinion, it makes almost zero sense to handle it this way.

Essentially, (what is meant to happen) when a user selects a country from the country list, the data stored in the selections `value` is used in an AJAX call to a PHP file `getCountryBorders.php` which I use the function `file_get_contents` to get the JSON data and return with the correct `featureCollection`/set of coordinates that matches the requested `iso` code and that is then passed to create an `L.geoJSON` layer in which the user can then trigger the bootstrap modal.

`<select>/<option:selected>` -> `value: iso_a3` -> AJAX `iso: iso_a3` request `iso` -> PHP cURL -> countryBorders.geo.json -> match `feature.properties.iso_a3 == 'iso'` -> $output = border coordinates -> AJAX `success function` generates a new `L.geoJSON` of the border coordinates of that country.

**What I need help with**:
This is the example PHP file I was given which of course is a bit naff:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $result=file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\vendors\json\countryBorders.geo.json');

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "success";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode;

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 
?>
```

I've tried to rewrite it and thought an `foreach` statement would suffice, but I've hit a bit of a brick wall regarding how to search through a `.json` file in PHP and capture the corresponding object's coordinate array.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $start=microtime( true );
    $file=file_get_contents('vendors\json\countryBorders.geo.json');

    $json=json_decode($file, true);

    foreach ($json->features->properties as $object) {
        if ($object->iso_a3 == $_REQUEST['iso']) {
            $output=array(
                'border'    => $object->coordinates,
                'status'    =>  array(
                    'code'          =>  200,
                    'name'          =>  'ok',
                    'description'   =>  'success',
                    'returnedIn'    =>  intval( ( microtime( true ) - $start ) * 1000 ) . 'ms'   
                ),
            ); 
        } else {
            $output=$json;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    exit( json_encode( $output ) );
    
?>
```

```
function setView() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryBorders.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            iso: $('#countrySelect option:selected').val() //getting iso from the value in the option
        },
        success: function(result) {

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                console.log(result['border']); //currently just logging the result

            }
      
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
};
```

Right now, the code isn't searching/iterating through the `countryBorders.geo.json` and I get a number of errors:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
script.js:69 parsererror
script.js:70 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.min.js:2
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0

Comment: Are you actually _required_ to use the `iso_a3` to identify the correct record? Because if not, you could simply use the _index_ of the elements inside `feature` as the value for your select options - then you can access the needed element _directly_ via that on the server side, and don't have to "search" the array for it.

Comment: Is `getCountryBorders.php` returning valid JSON? That parse error suggests it might be returning HTML (or something else with a < in it).

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately I am required to use the `iso_a3`. Although thank you for your suggestion, I wish I could go that route instead.

Comment: @peeebeee It isn't, and I'm not sure why. I checked out the link CBroe commented and it would be likely that it is returning HTML and not JSON. I'm still trying to work out why, and it could be something to do with my AJAX call itself. Anywho, the `parsererror` is just one of the problems now bundled on top!

Comment: Use your browser dev tools, network panel, to inspect the response for that AJAX request. If your PHP code created any errors or warning, then it is very likely that you get HTML tags in the output due to that (default for config option `html_errors` is true.)

Comment: Regarding the filtering inside your loop - what is the `else` branch supposed to be good for? Remove that. And instead of overwriting `$output` each time the condition is true, _add_ new items to it - initialize it properly as an empty array before your loop, and then inside, do `$output[] = ...`

Comment: Yep, okay it appears to be an issue with accessing properties in an array.
b>Warning</b>:  Attempt to read property "feature" on array in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\libs\php\getCountryBorders.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\libs\php\getCountryBorders.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

Comment: Changing `foreach ($json->feature as $object)...` to `foreach ($json["features"] as $object)` resolved that issue