# How to convert response.text() to JSON with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

In the following

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("faulty-endpoint");
      const data = await response.text()
      console.log('data', data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    } finally {
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

How do I turn the response.text() data back to json? I can't do

```
const data = await response.json()
```

Because then I `console.log` nothing. I want it to be `JSON` format so I can save it into a `useState` array that I can `map` across.

Comment: "Because then I console.log nothing" <--- What do you mean by this? You can use `console.log` with arbitrary objects, so you **can** use `await response.json()`.

Comment: Why not use `response.json()` in the first place? And it sounds like you don't actually want JSON, you want an object, which you can get with from a json string via [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Comment: @Dai if I console.log data after await response.json(), I don't console.log anything

Comment: @rayhatfield I would like an array of objects to map across, using response.json() does not allow me to see the data. It seems i can only use response.text() to read the data from the fetch url

Comment: `response.json()` will return the array, assuming the response is well-formed JSON, and there's no reason you can't `console.log` that object. If you're not seeing console output I suspect there's something else wrong. Either your request is failing or the response isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @rayhatfield I think the response is not a well formed-JSON and is a string. After checking the Preview of how the data is formed, it seems to a string instead of the regular array of objects.

Comment: @rayhatfield edited post to show the Preview. Could you confirm that it is not a well formed-JSON?

Comment: It *does* look like valid JSON. Have you *removed* `response.text()` when 
you used `response.json()`?

Comment: yes, I replaced response.text() with response.json() and got nothing. Looking more closely, I see that there is a comma at the end of the array. Maybe that is messing up the response?

Comment: Yes, valid JSON can't have trailing commas. Can you fix it where it's coming from?

Comment: You could chop the comma off the `response.text()` and then `JSON.parse()` it back into an object.

Comment: @rayhatfield Sure you could, but I'd try to first fix the source (the backend) if it's fixable.

Comment: @rayhatfield The person who made the backend is telling me to fix it on the frontend, turn it into JSON, and use the data that way...is that even possible?

Comment: @FZs OP says in a [comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71182406/how-to-convert-response-text-to-json-with-react?noredirect=1#comment125826192_71182594) that he doesn't control the API.

Comment: @dev_el Yes, it's possible. See [youdateme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71182677/636077), or just do `const obj = JSON.parse(text.replace(/,$/, ''))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of that trailing comma, you can remove it first, then use `JSON.parse`:

```js
let text = await response.text();

// if trailing comma present, remove last character by slicing it off
// -1 in slice is the same as text.length - 1
if (text.endsWith(",")) text = text.slice(0, -1);

const data = JSON.parse(text);
```

This isn't the best or cleanest solution however; ideally the API should return valid JSON...

Comment: You could also do this with `JSON.parse(text.replace(/,$/, ''))`, eliminating the need for the conditional trimming. If the comma isn't there the replace doesn't do anything.

Comment: Works excellently too! I just thought regex would be overkill/severely minor perf drain.

Comment: With the trailing `$` it should be super efficient.

Comment: [proof of concept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71182995/636077)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [working proof-of-concept implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-wave-0i61xn?file=/src/App.js) of [youdateme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71182677/636077).

I'm faking the request here to avoid CORS issues and such, but the response is copied from the endpoint in your question.

(Note: I had to re-escape the quotes around `\"Hello World\"` in the last record in the exported template string.)

It does what [youdateme suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71182677/636077) and it works.

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fakeRequest();
    const data = JSON.parse(response.replace(/,$/, ""));
    setData(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

fetchData();
```

If this solves your problem you should accept youdateme's answer.

Answer (score 0):

JSON and a JavaScript object look similar, but they're different. JSON is only a string that's formatted like a JavaScript object. See: [Working with JSON - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

To map across, you need it to be a JavaScript object, not JSON.

Use `JSON.parse(yourResponse)` to parse a JSON string into a JavaScript object (or array, etc.). See: [JSON.parse from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

To convert a JavaScript object into a JSON string, you may use `JSON.stringify(yourObject)`

Comment: Could you please apply your answer to the code above? I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `JSON.parse(responseData)`

```
const fetchData = async () => {
try {
  const response = await fetch("faulty-endpoint");
  const data = await response.text()
  console.log('data', JSON.parse(data));
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
 } finally {
  setLoading(false)
 }
}
```

Other solution:

```
fetch('targetedURL')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I tried `let test = JSON.parse(await response.text());` but console logging test gives me nothing!

Comment: I get the following error

SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 2756
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fetchData

Comment: Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59192631/10427807

Comment: Have you tried this? fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));

Comment: Yes I think why your solution is not working is because the data is not well-formed JSON and is a string, pls refer to my question where I added an image showing the Preview to not be an array of objects, but a string.

Comment: Yes you got the point. Could you try the other solution of my answer? Should work.

Comment: I get the same error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 2756

I'm pretty sure this is because the endpoint is not well-formed JSON.

Comment: Yeah thats the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to the formatting of the response returned by the api.
The api returns a trailing ',' at the end of the array which makes it an invalid JSON object.
remove that ',' from the response and

> const data = await response.json()

should work.

Comment: I can't remove the , from the response because I don't have control of that API endpoint. It seems this question is impossible to solve until the endpoint is fixed to give a proper JSON object instead of a string...