# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in nextJs creating sitemap

Tags: json, next.js, sitemap

I'm trying to generate dynamic sitemap with nextjs.
It works locally, but when I try to deploy to vercel, SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0  oocured.

My source code is below.

```
export default async function sitemap() {
  const res = await fetch('https://example.com/api/games');
  const games = await res.json();
  const gameUrls = games.map((game) => ({
    url: `http://localhost:3000/Games/${encodeURIComponent(game.title)}`,
    lastModified: new Date().toISOString(),
  }));
  return [...gameUrls];
}
```

When I change the fetch url to 'http://localhost:3000/api/games' and run locally, everything is going well.

When I print the response, the result is below.

```
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 404,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 11159.292941000022,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 11159.292941000022,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 0,
      decodedBodySize: 0,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'Not Found',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      cookies: null,
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    cookies: null,
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(15) {
      'access-control-allow-origin' => [Object],
      'age' => [Object],
      'cache-control' => [Object],
      'connection' => [Object],
      'content-disposition' => [Object],
      'content-encoding' => [Object],
      'content-type' => [Object],
      'date' => [Object],
      'etag' => [Object],
      'server' => [Object],
      'strict-transport-security' => [Object],
      'x-matched-path' => [Object],
      'x-vercel-cache' => [Object],
      'x-vercel-id' => [Object],
      'transfer-encoding' => [Object]
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

404 error occured, but I'm sure that it's connected to api and it returned results.

Comment: Have you had a look at this question? Maybe you also have html instead of json in the body.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280274/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0?rq=2

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.
The folution was deploying only api first, then I could add sitemap.js.
Otherwise I couldn't call the api from sitemap.js.